# Java Can't Read font

Tags: java, fonts

Ok, so I have a problem using a custom font. Basically I get a custom font I downloaded off the internet and use it in my program. When I run the program in Eclipse (the editor I use), everything works fine, and there is no problem. BUT, whenever I export it to a jar from eclipse, or try to run it from the command prompt I get this very annoying error:

```
java.io.IOException: Can't read REVOLUTION.ttf
    at java.awt.Font.createFont(Unknown Source)
    at TowerDefense.<init>(TowerDefense.java:55)
    at TowerDefense.main(TowerDefense.java:302)
```

I get that along with a bunch of null pointer exceptions because of where I use the font. But I don't know why it says it can't read it. Here is  the code that creates the font:

```
try {
        revolution = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("REVOLUTION.ttf"));
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        ge.registerFont(revolution);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**FOLDER LAYOUT**

TowerDefense

```
src
    default package
        TowerDefense.java
        Game.java
        DragTest.java
JRE System Library
REVOLUTION.ttf
neuropol.ttf
```

Comment: Is the font definitely included in the Jar? I'd you are running on the command line the font needs to be included on the classpath.

Comment: Is the font included with the JAR? Where is it located?

Comment: Yes, it is included in the JAR. I see your thought process, but I still get that error even when I'm just running the JAVA file. And yes, everything is in the proper spots, and references it correctly. @KLibby

Comment: @VinceEmigh look above

Comment: @Ryan Mind telling us where it's located? My guess is it's located directly in the project, not within any specific folder, but I can't be sure. And have you tried accessing the resource (the font) via [getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: @VinceEmigh the JAVA file is located in a "src" folder, then the font is located in the same place as the src folder, NOT inside the src folder. And I'm not to familiar with getResource (I'm fairly new to java).

Comment: @VinceEmigh it's not in source, it's in the same location as source

Comment: I'm sorry, misread that. For 11thdimension's answer, did you move the font to `com.example.font`? Cause that's where it's attempting to load the font from

Comment: @VinceEmigh I just have `...getResourceAsStream("REVOLUTION.ttf")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not access contents of a JAR using File API.

You have to load the font file using Classloader's `getResourceAsStream` method. For this to work you'll have to put the font file on classpath.

So you code becomes:

```
revolution = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("REVOLUTION.ttf"));
```

If font is included inside a package or folder in JAR, then path would change accordingly.

```
getResourceAsStream("com/example/font/REVOLUTION.ttf"); // if font is present inside com.example.font package
```

Comment: this creates an error in Eclipse: "java.IO.IOException: Problem reading font data"

Comment: Check if your font file is accessible to Classloader, it has to be on classpath. Also verify if it's working with the exported JAR.

Comment: Can you post the structure of your Eclipse project including the font file location in it ?

Comment: Put the "REVOLUTION.ttf" in `default package`, then it should work.

Comment: That fixed everything, thank you so much I've had this problem forever and finally posted something. Again, thank you so much