# Adding new font JAVA

Tags: java

I have a porblem with this code:

```
Font fontek;


public GUI() {


    setSize(1024, 960);
    setTitle("FCM");
    setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    try {
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("DIN 1451 Std Engschrift.oft"));

        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        ge.registerFont(font);
        this.fontek = font;
    } catch (IOException | FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JLabel label_a = new JLabel("label text");
    label_a.setBounds(104, 20, 150, 20);
    label_a.setFont(fontek);
    add(label_a);

}
```

I'm getting this kind of java.io.IOException: 
Can't read DIN 1451 Std Engschrift.oft

I think that there is a problem with my directory, but when I compile this my text says only "_". It doeasn't look like my font. Is there a way I can do this properly? Maybe there is specified directory where I should put this font in?

Comment: What is the value of `new File("DIN 1451 Std Engschrift.oft").exists()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466697/java-cant-read-font

Comment: false, how i can change this?

Comment: Piotr, don't forget to notify Andy of your comment/response to him by prepending the `@` symbol in front of his name: @AndyTurner.

Comment: Your code currently assumes that your font file is in the *current directory.*  If the font file is in your project, you should access it not with the File class but with the Class.getResourceAsStream method.  If the file is not in your project, pass an absolute path to the File constructor (that is, a path starting with a drive letter in Windows, or `/` in other operating systems).

Comment: How should I put this method into my code? Is this a static method?

Comment: @vgr I've changed it for:
`this.fontek = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, GUI.class.getResourceAsStream("DIN 1451 Std Engschrift.oft"));`
and now i'm getting this error:
Problem reading font data.

Comment: Is that a FontFormatException message?

Comment: java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
 at java.awt.Font.createFont0(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Font.createFont(Unknown Source)
 at cardmaker.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:38)
 at cardmaker.Main.main(Main.java:14)
This is this message.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and solved it by passing full path to font file - for example "C:\fonts\FONT.oft" for Windows.